# Reset gif without downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

there is any way to reset(play again) a gif without downloading it?

I was using the following code to restart the gif:

```
rplImg = new Image();
 var d = new Date();
 rplImg.src = "imagens/Mex_Gif.gif?" + d.valueOf();

 $('#baixo').css('background-image', 'url('+rplImg.src+')');
```

That way the browser restart the animation because he thinks its another file and download again.

How can I animate the gif without downloading again? The animation shold run everytime the user clicks a button, I can't redownload it everytime.

Comment: Maybe try using embed base 64 data directly to the image

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way.

Comment: The vast majority of browsers would have cached the image so strictly speaking this method likely won't result in the image being downloaded again.

Comment: @adeneo this is the question, one of the solutions redownload the gif. My gif is a div background if Iremove the attribute background and add the same image, will it work?

Comment: @Emissary if the gif is cached, it won't animate again. But changing the final of the string the browser download it again and animate, it was the only way that I found but not acceptable due the gif size.

Comment: have you tried actually removing it from the DOM and re-appending it - rather than just setting the `src` attribute as that works fine for me.